# Proving that a successor cardinal $k^+$ is regular, given that $k$ is an infinite cardinal and using a different definition of cofinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have been trying to prove that if $k$ is an infinite cardinal number, then its successor $k^+$ is regular, that is $\operatorname{cf}(k^+)=k^+$.

In my class we have defined cofinality in the following way:

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{cf}(k)&=\min\left\{I \subseteq k\mid \text{for some family of cardinal numbers } (k_i)_{i \in I}\\
(\forall i \in I) [k_i<k]\,\&\,\sum_{i\in I} k_i = k\right\}
\end{align*}$$

I tried a proof by contradiction, supposing that $\operatorname{cf}(k^+)<k^+$ and using König's theorem, all to no avail.
The problem can be found in the book *Notes on Set Theory* by *Yannis Moschovakis* as **x.9.17.**

Comment: Did you mean the minimum $\color{red}|I\color{red}|$?

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $\lambda < \kappa^+$ iff $\lambda \le \kappa$.

Comment: You must use AC (Axiom of Choice) to prove $k^+$ regular. I recommend Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs by K. Kunen.

Comment: Maybe think about it for $\omega_1$ first. This essentially reduces to the countable union of countable sets being countable. (Also this should clarify the role of AC.) I don’t think König helps here... all that seems to show is that we will violate the GCH, not arrive at a contradiction.